# Segmentation fault on c implementation of linked list when adding nodes

Tags: c, file-io, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I got a segfault with this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct _node
{
    char *buffer;           
    struct _node *next;     
    int node_count;        
} node;

typedef struct _list
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;

list *node_list;

int list_node_lookup(list *l, char *buffer)
{
    node *temp = l->head;
    while(temp)
    {
        if (strcmp(temp->buffer, buffer) == 0)
        {
            /* We got it earlier */
            temp->node_count++;

            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}

int adding_to_list(list *l, char *buffer)
{
    int ret;
    char *tmp = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer) + 1));
    node *new_node = (node *)malloc(sizeof(struct _node));

    /* Empty list */
    if (l->head == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(tmp, buffer);
        new_node->buffer = tmp;
        new_node->node_count = 0;
        l->head = l->tail = new_node;
        l->head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        /* The list is not empty */
        ret = list_node_lookup(l, buffer);
        if (ret == 1)
        {
            fprintf(stdout, "Got it before\n");
        }
        else
        {
            strcpy(tmp, buffer);
            new_node->buffer = tmp;
            new_node->node_count = 0;
            l->tail->next = new_node;
            l->tail = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
            fprintf(stdout, "Adding this cust : %s\n", buffer);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE    *cust;
    char    buf[BUFSIZ];
    DIR* cust_dir;
    struct dirent* input;

    node_list = (list *) malloc(sizeof(struct _list));
    if (node_list == NULL)
    {
            return 1;
    }
    node_list->head = node_list->tail = NULL;

    if (NULL == (cust_dir = opendir("cust_dir"))) 
    {
        return 1;
    }
    while ((input = readdir(cust_dir))) 
    {
            if (!strcmp (input->d_name, "."))
                continue;
            if (!strcmp (input->d_name, ".."))  
                continue;

            cust = fopen(input->d_name, "r");

            while (fgets(buf, BUFSIZ, cust) != NULL)
            {
                adding_to_list(node_list, buf);
            }
                    fclose(cust);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When i test my code with a directory that contain this two files(they contain empty lines), i got strange output and seg fault.

I use this file twice (customers.txt and customers_copy.txt) in the same directory:

```
1
2
3
4    Kristina   Chung   H   Kristina H. Chung   Chung, Kristina H.
5    Paige  Chen    H   Paige H. Chen   Chen, Paige H.
6    Sherri Melton  E   Sherri E. Melton    Melton, Sherri E.
7    Gretchen   Hill    I   Gretchen I. Hill    Hill, Gretchen I.
8    Karen  Puckett U   Karen U. Puckett    Puckett, Karen U.
9    Patrick    Song    O   Patrick O. Song Song, Patrick O.
10    Elsie Hamilton    A   Elsie A. Hamilton   Hamilton, Elsie A.
11   
12    Hazel Bender  E   Hazel E. Bender Bender, Hazel E.
13
```

The first three lines are empty (when i use one file all is ok, but this multiple files i got a segfault).

Thanks for your help, to understand what's wrong.

Comment: After you read the first file you never close the fp cust, before you go onto the next file, that might cause some problems

Comment: @GregBrown : thanks, i close it but did not change any thing.

Comment: The first thing you should do when getting a segmentation fault, is to run your program in a debugger. This will help you pinpoint the location of the error, and also let you examine variables to help you figure out the reason of the problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg : the debugger show an error on the line of fgets(_IO_fgets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a node to the list (to the tail of the list), you don't set the `next` pointer of that node to NULL. That means that the next time you do a lookup, you will call `strcmp` with invalid pointers. This in itself could cause a segmentation fault.

The simple solution is to set `next` to NULL as soon as you allocate the node.

Also, if the node is already in the list, you allocate `tmp` but never use it. That would leak memory. This is similar to the comment by Greg Brown - you are also leaking file descriptors and file handles (you never close `cust`).

**[EDIT]**

The problem is that you are reading the directory "cust_dir", so you are getting names of files that are in the directory (e.g. "customers.txt"). You then open the file without adding "cust_dir/" to the file name.

So if by accident you also have the file in the current directory, it works. But otherwise, `cust` is NULL (because `input->d_name` is the name of a file inside "cust_dir", not in the current directory), and you then try to read data from a NULL file pointer. This causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: Thanks, but nothing has changed after adding new_node->next = NULL;

Comment: @iPadDevloperJr You are calling `fclose` with `input`, but you should be calling with `cust`. That also causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: @iPadDevloperJr can you give us an idea about the input? Can you find a smallish input that you can paste here and still causes a problem?

Comment: i post an input in the origianl post my input dir : contain two files : customers.txt and customers_copy.txt which contain the same data as posted

Comment: sorry this is not true, i added the full path of the directory but still inchanged : "Segmentation fault: 11"

Comment: @iPadDevloperJr can you check `cust` after you call `fopen`, to make sure it's not NULL?

Comment: it's not NULL i printf the name of the opened file to the stdout